# Problems creating new Rails project: "There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack"

Tags: ruby

I've never seen this before, and a simple Google search for this exact message turns up nothing. Stack Overflow is

```
run  bundle install
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your   system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL   certificates, see
bit.ly/ssl-certs. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https'   to 'http'.
```

I followed the instructions on this page, and came up empty handed:

http://www.beginnerruby.com/rails-troubleshooting/fixing-opensslbundler-issue-for-rails-on-debian/

Anybody have any ideas?

Mac OSX Lion using RubyMine.

Comment: I am having similar problems, and seems to relate to recent changes to support Ruby 2.0 release. I found http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html but unfortunately it didn't work for me (hence not posting it as an answer for you - but do give it a read!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed [these instructions](http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html) with no obvious results. Reading the comments somebody asked if the Terminal was re-opened. So, I closed/opened the terminal. That fixed my problem. I'm using SnowLeopard.

```
$ brew update
$ brew install openssl
$ brew link openssl --force
$ brew install curl-ca-bundle
$ brew tap raggi/ale
$ brew install openssl-osx-ca
```

Comment: I will try this when I get home. I can only hope that it's something this trivial!

Answer (score 3):

I think interpreting the exception should be straightforward(though I may be wrong) change 
source 'https://rubygems.org' 
at the top of your Gemfile to:
source 'http://rubygems.org'

Comment: I can verify that this worked round my similar problem, however it is not terribly satisfactory as I am on a shared repo and other devs are not having the same problem, and are using https successfully. Something odd appears to have happened recently to certificates on rubygems.org, and my Mac for some reason has not kept up properly.

Comment: @bjhaid I did not asked the original question. I did give you an upvote though

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using `rvm`.

First, install OpenSSL rvm package:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

Then re-install your ruby version (in my case, 2.0.0p247) pointing to this package:

```
rvm reinstall 2.0.0-p247 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Leave the current project folder and enter it again:

```
cd .
```

Now you can run `bundle install`:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions here which worked: http://gistflow.com/posts/916-fix-mac-os-x-rubygems-ssl-problem

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having similar issues:

By running:

`sudo rvm osx-ssl-certs status all`

you'll probably see your certificates are out of date. It'll say something like this:

`Certificates for /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem: Old.`.

You need to renew, so run this:

`sudo rvm osx-ssl-certs update all`.

Firing the status command again should give something like:

`Certificates for /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem: Up to date.`

Happy days, problem fixed.